# Wrap a struct inside a property into NSValue

Tags: objective-c, struct

I use NSValue to wrap a struct defined by me, but when the struct is accesed through a @property I get this error: Address of property expression requested.

Can this be done using the property or I shall store the struct in variable first?

Non-valid code:

```
NSValue *previousTileObj = [NSValuevalue:&self.previousTile withObjCType:@encode(RobotTile)];
```

Valid code:

```
RobotTile localPreviousTile = self.previousTile;
NSValue *previousTileObj = [NSValuevalue:&localPreviousTile withObjCType:@encode(RobotTile)];
```

Comment: Did you try removing the & from the first one?

Comment: Yes, sure. In that case the error is: Sending 'RobotTile' (aka 'struct RobotTile') to parameter of incompatible type 'const void *';

Answer (score 1):

You cannot take the address of the result of a call to the accessor of an object's property.

This is because the statement `self.previousTitle` is just syntactic sugar for the Objective-C message call `[self previousTitle]`, which has semantics similar to that for function calls in that the resulting value has no real location in memory, and therefor it cannot have its address taken with the `&` operator.

You can, however, cheat the result into an addressable object by wrapping the accessor call within a C array literal. Since arrays are essentially pointers to their first element, this will result in a pointer to the desired data.

```
NSValue *previousTileObj = [NSValue value:(RobotTile []){self.previousTile} 
                             withObjCType:@encode(RobotTile)];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take advantage of [structure support in key-value coding](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/DataTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002171-SW2) and do:

```
NSValue *previousTileObj = [self valueForKey:@"previousTile"];
```